# Magento 2.1.0 : How to get custom table data in phtml file

Tags: magento2, phtml, resource-model

I have created a custom module : **Ved_Mymodule** 
File structure of the module is as follows:

```
Ved
└───Mymodule
    │   registration.php
    │
    ├───etc
    │       module.xml
    │
    ├───Model
    │   │   News.php
    │   │
    │   └───Resource
    │       │   News.php
    │       │
    │       └───News
    │               Collection.php
    │
    ├───Setup
    │       InstallSchema.php
    │       UpdateSchema.php
    │
    └───view
        └───frontend
            │   requirejs-config.js
            │
            ├───layout
            │       deafult.xml
            │
            └───web
                ├───css
                └───js
                        customCatalogAddToCart.js
                        InstallSchema.php
```

Using this module, one table with name ved_mymodule is created. 'id' is the primary key in that column.

Here are the files :

**Ved\Mymodule\Model\News.php :**

```
<?php

namespace Ved\Mymodule\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class News extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
         * Define resource model
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('Ved\Mymodule\Model\Resource\News');
        }
    }
```

**Ved\Mymodule\Model\Resource\News.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Ved\Mymodule\Model\Resource;

use Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb;

class News extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
         * Define main table
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('ved_mymodule', 'id');
        }
    }
```

**Ved\Mymodule\Model\Resource\News\Collection.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Ved\Mymodule\Model\Resource\News;

use Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
/**
     * Define model & resource model
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'Ved\Mymodule\Model\News',
            'Ved\Mymodule\Model\Resource\News'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the Data by following below steps.

1. Create a Block file or if you already created a block for your template use below code in the block in your module.
2. Add below code to block

   > ```
   >  public function __construct(
   >     Context $context,
   >     \Ved\Mymodule\Model\NewsFactory $modelNameFactory,
   >     array $data = array()
   > ) {
   >     $this->_modelFactory = $modelFactory;
   >     parent::__construct($context, $data);
   > }
   > public function getCollection(){
   >     return $this->_modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
   > }
   > ```
3. use get  `getCollection` in your template ( $block->getCollection() )
4. Loop through each of the collection result.
5. Assume you know how to create Block and template.

Hope this answer help you.

Comment: I have not created a block and template. First I need to try this then I will let you know. Thank you for this.

Comment: Using your answer and following [alanstorm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_crud_models_for_database_access) article, I got the solution. Thank you.

Comment: is this $modelNameFactory and _modelFactory  same?

Comment: @Mujahidh yes, we are using class object by $this->_modelFactory passing into constructor.